# Use Linq and Lambda to include default

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two lists: `relatedContact` and `fileContactIds`. 
I am using the query to loop the relatedContacts list and return value of userClientCode (which I will make the image name) only if it is also in the `fileContactIds` list. How can I put in a value (eg: "Default") if the value isn't in the second list ?

```
var result = relatedContact.SelectMany(rc => rc.contacts.Select(pc => new RelatedContactsDescription
                {
                    imageUrl = mappedRelatedContactsPath + pc.userclientcode + ".jpg",
                    userclientcode = pc.userclientcode,
                    description = rc.clienttaxonomy,
                    fullname = pc.fullname,
                    email = pc.contactdetails != null && pc.contactdetails.Count >= 1 ? pc.contactdetails[0].contactdata : "",
                    address = pc.contactdetails != null && pc.contactdetails.Count >= 2 ? pc.contactdetails[1].contactdata : "",
                    phoneNumber = pc.contactdetails != null && pc.contactdetails.Count >= 3 ? pc.contactdetails[2].contactdata : "",
                    populated = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pc.userclientcode) ||
                                string.IsNullOrEmpty(pc.fullname) ||
                                string.IsNullOrEmpty(pc.contactdetails[0].contactdata) ? false : true,
                }))
                .Where(el => fileContactIds.Contains(el.userclientcode)).ToList();
```

I have read: [Lambdas and Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344019/linq-and-lambda-expression) and [Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda) [First or Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923103/how-to-do-this-in-lambda-expression-or-linq) etc but all I can see is how to get matching data from both not also how to put a "fall-back" or default value if they don't match.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Standard is `DefaultIfEmpty`

Comment: you can use left join

Comment: Btw which column needs Default Value, userclientcode  is it ?

Comment: @Stranger How to use left join in linq - lambda expression?

Comment: Not related but why do you combine everything into 1 line? (`select`, `selectmany`, `where`, `tolist`, `count`, `sisnullorempty`, `count`, `if-else`...)?

Comment: @vipin Check my answer underneath, it contains two options, one using Left Join, which is achieved using `GroupJoin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code do the following changes:

- Remove the `Where` clause, as that's not serving the purpose, you need `Default` where `UserClientCode` doesn't exist, you don't want to filter them out using `Where`
- Change the following in `SelectMany` call:

  `userclientcode = pc.userclientcode`

To

```
 userclientcode = fileContactIds.Contains(pc.userclientcode) ? 
                  pc.userclientcode : "Default"
```

You may consider using a `Left Join` post creating a flattened list using `SelectMany`, but that would be a Round about way to achieve it, which is simply achieve while creating a flattened List.

**Using Left Join**

Following is the code option for Left Join, it needs `GroupJoin` in C#:

```
var result = relatedContact.SelectMany(rc => rc.contacts.Select(pc => {pc})
                           .GroupJoin(fileContactIds, pc => pc.userclientcode,
                                      fc => fc.ContactId,new {pc,fc})
                           .SelectMany(
                            x => x.fc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            (x,y) => new RelatedContactsDescription
                            {
                               userclientcode = (y == null) ? "Default":x.pc.userclientcode,
                            .........(fill remaining as per original logic)
                            });
```

**How does it work**

- Create Anonymous List from `relatedContact` using `SelectMany`
- `GroupJoin` with fileContactIds. where I have assume field is `ContactId`
- Create an Anonymous List with Data from both collections, where Unmatched records from fileContactIds will be empty being `LeftJoin`
- In final `SelectMany`explicity make the fileContactIds empty values null, then during data selection, so what I have suggested earlier for null values, fill "Default", else the specific value

Comment: I still think He should use left join

Comment: What I have suggested is much simpler and would be done while creating the final list. As I have suggested, yes `Join` is an option but its the matter of simplicity in my view

Comment: @Stranger check out the code for Left Join too, which is achieved using `GroupJoin`

Comment: @Stranger Also Check I have explained its working, this is good example:
http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1108/linq-inner-join-left-outer-join-on-two-lists-in-c-with-example

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I am trying to implement your first suggestion but on getting what you mean when you say remove Where clause. Do you mean after Select I should then filter ? Also your left join is showing many errors and extra brackets are inserted. Also please remember I don't just want the userclientcode, I want to match this to the contactId and map into RelatedContactsDescription object

Comment: @AfshinGhazi, its like, `Where` clause in your code is only for the purpose of filtering the `Ids` based on `fileContactIds`, but your challenge is you want Default value for Ids which doesn't exist, not just filter them out, so I have shifted the filtering inside the `SelectMany` and `Where` clause is redundant as it cannot help you to get the Default values.